# MongoDB's ObjectId relationship in Schema doesn't work after server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a simple mongo schema in NodeJs using the mongoose package.

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    author: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    description: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
};
```

And when I want to test whether the author of the post is the current user, if the project was created on the current server session (aka without restarting) it will work. But if I restart the server the `Object Id's` are not equal.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you aren't signing in as the same author or somehow aren't getting the same Id assigned as an author. What's the other ObjectId that's not equal to the `author` ObjectId?

Comment: Here's how I use it: I create a project as a user. The only user in the database I might add. The Project is created fine. On the frontend I want allow the creator of that project be able to edit it. I check if the current user's id is the same as the project author's id. When the server is on the same session, it works perfectly. The problem arises when I restart the server (Using grunt watch, so whenever I change/save anything it does a restart) then the current user's id changes and is not the same

Answer (score 0):

Keep the type of author as String. 
Once you fetch the current user's data from session, you can perform

```
user._id.toString()
```

to get the string representation of objectID where I user is the dbObject. You can then look this **id** up in the ProjectSchema collection for any author match